# MATLAB: combine rows with similar values

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB and I am trying to combine rows with similar values (I have thousands of rows), for example

```
1   NaN

1   NaN

1   NaN

2   9

2   26.5

2   21.5

2   18

2   24.5

2   12

2   22.5

3   NaN

3   NaN

3   NaN

3   NaN

4   18.5

4   22

4   35.5
```

...
...
...

to

```
1   NaN     NaN     NaN             

2   9       26.5    21.5    18      24.5    12  22.5

3   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN         

4   18.5    22      35.5
```

can any one please help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure you do not just want to remove all the `nan` entries? That is easily done with `A(isnan(A))=[];`, assuming you called your matrix `A`. There is little similarity in "9 26.5 21.5 18 24.5 12 22.5", besides the fact that they're all numbers, instead of `nan`. To do what you asked you'd need cells, which are probably not what you are looking for in this case.

Comment: This can't be done with normal arrays.  Each row has to have same number of columns, but your desired output isn't so.  You can work with cell arrays if you wish.  Please confirm that this is what you want and if so, we can work with this.

Comment: rayryeng: I am okay using cell arrays if I can combine as I mentioned previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with normal arrays. Each row has to have same number of columns, but your desired output isn't so. You can work with cell arrays if you wish.

If cell arrays are an option, the best way to tackle this IMHO would be to use an `accumarray/sort/cellfun` pipeline.  First use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to group all of the values together that belong to the same ID, so the first column in your case.  Each group would thus be a cell array.  However, a consequence with `accumarray` is that the values that come in per group are **unordered**.  Therefore, what you'd have to group instead are the **locations** of the values instead.  You'd sort these locations and what is output is a cell array where each cell are a list of indices you'd access in the original data.

You'd then call [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) as the last step to use the indices access the actual data itself.

Something like this comes to mind, assuming your data is stored in `X` and it's a two-column array.

```
ind = (1 : size(X,1)).'; %'
out_ind = accumarray(X(:,1), ind, [], @(x) {sort(x)});
out = cellfun(@(x) X(x,2), out_ind, 'uni', 0);
```

We thus get:

```
>> celldisp(out)

out{1} =

   NaN
   NaN
   NaN



out{2} =

    9.0000
   26.5000
   21.5000
   18.0000
   24.5000
   12.0000
   22.5000



out{3} =

   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN



out{4} =

   18.5000
   22.0000
   35.5000
```